# Upgrade from ASP.NET MVC 3 with ASP view engine to MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I upgrade my project having ASP.NET MVC3.0(visual studio 2010) using ASP view engine into ASP.NET MVC5.0 Visual Studio 2013.

I started my project 6 year back in Asp.Net MVC 2.0 using ASP view engine & Visual Studio2008. I migrate my project to MVC 3.0 Uisng VS2010 but now I have to create WebAPI 2.0 and other new feature of VS2013 or 2015. So I have to upgrade my project into MVC 5.0 and VS2013.

I am worrying, Is new version of MVC 5.0 support ASP view engine ?

Comment: There is no option to add an ASPX view, but you can use aspx files as before. just add a file with .aspx extension and everything works fine.

Comment: You can get .aspx views to run in MVC 5. But converting these to Razor is easy -- Mostly converting `<% %>` into `@`